# Facing virus attack in Magento

Tags: security

we are facing attack of stats.g.doubleclick.net virus in my website . Please suggest some way to stop it as people are redirected from checkout page to shopping cart page . Please help asap.

Answer (score 2):

I think, this is not the right place to get help "asap" to remove a virus from your site. Better take the site offline and let somebody look over it **on site** (hoster, developer, security expert)

But base on the sparse information, I can tell you that much:

- doubleclick.net itself is not malicious, it's an **advertising platform**. So if people get redirected there, at least they don't necessarily get a **virus**, they see advertisment and the bad guys get money from it.
- that doesn't mean, ads cannot link to malicious or infected sites. Online advertisement is a terrible snake pit
- "people are redirected from checkout page to shopping cart page" does not sound like a virus at all, more like a bug in the checkout. This happens if an error occurs in one of the checkout steps. You can confirm that by inspecting the AJAX responses in the browser console, then examine your webserver error logs to find the error.